# How to loop through all the buttons to a click event listener

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm making a simple game for a project and need the corresponding value of each button to be displayed in the input when clicked.

I am able to use "getElementById" successfully with the following JS:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
const button1 = document.getElementById("button-one");

button1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   document.getElementById("user-input").value += button1.value;
   document.getElementById("user-input").focus();
});
```

I could of course just repeat this code for all buttons 0-9 but I would like to use "loop" if possible to accomplish this with just one block of code.
I made the following attempt by just trying to emulate the above code that worked for one "id" and just switching out "button1" for a loop through "buttons" (I've tried both "querySelectorAll" and "getElementsByClassName").
I get the error: "button.addEventListener is not a function."
I don't understand because in the successful single button code "button1.addEventListener("click", function(e)" is not a function either but it works...
Below is the loop attempt, followed by the entire page:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("td>button");
for(var button = 0; button < buttons.length; button++)
{
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.getElementById("user-input").value += button.value;
   document.getElementById("user-input").focus();
});
}
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../normalize.css">
<style>
input {
    margin-top: 10px;    
}

table {    
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: auto;    
    margin-top: 10px;    
}
</style>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    
 // This works   
const button1 = document.getElementById("button-one");

button1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   document.getElementById("user-input").value += button1.value;
   document.getElementById("user-input").focus();
});


//This doesn't work
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("td>button");
for(var button = 0; button < buttons.length; button++)
{
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.getElementById("user-input").value += button.value;
   document.getElementById("user-input").focus();
});
}
});


</script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   
<main>
    <input  id="user-input">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" value="1" id="button-one" class="calc">1</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="2" class="calc">2</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="3" class="calc">3</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" value="4" class="calc">4</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="5" class="calc">5</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="6" class="calc">6</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" value="7" class="calc">7</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="8" class="calc">8</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="9" class="calc">9</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" value="0" class="calc">0</button></td>
            <td colspan="2"><button type="button" value="CLEAR" id="clear" class="calc">CLEAR</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a large number of event listeners will hinder your application's performance. Hence in such cases you can use the Event Delegation technique.
If you want to read more about this, I found [this link](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) very resourceful. In case you have any queries hit me up in the comments.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#user-input");
const table = document.querySelector("table");

table.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    //Since we only want to register button clicks inside the table and not any clicks on the blank space between the buttons.
    if(e.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
        if(e.target.id === "clear") {
            input.value = "";
        } else {
            input.value += e.target.value;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Async JS</title>
    <script src="promises.js" defer></script>
    <style>
        input {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        table {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            width: auto;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <input  id="user-input">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" value="1" class="calc">1</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" value="2" class="calc">2</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" value="3" class="calc">3</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" value="4" class="calc">4</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" value="5" class="calc">5</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" value="6" class="calc">6</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" value="7" class="calc">7</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" value="8" class="calc">8</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" value="9" class="calc">9</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" value="0" class="calc">0</button></td>
                <td colspan="2"><button type="button" value="CLEAR" id="clear" class="calc">CLEAR</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Smooth as butter. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could/should use a "[*for...of*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)" or a "[*for...in*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)" loop. In this case, a *for...of* is what you seem to need.

```
const input = document.getElementById("user-input")

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("td > button");
      for (var button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener("click", function(e) { ... }
```

EDIT: If you are looking to concatenate each number into the input (eg. "123") use this in place of the ellipsis:

```
  if (e.target.id === "clear") {
    input.value = "";
  } else {
    input.value += e.target.value;
  }
  document.getElementById("user-input").focus();
```

Full snippet version:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const input = document.getElementById("user-input")
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("td > button");

  for (var button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if (e.target.id === "clear") {
        input.value = "";
      } else {
        input.value += e.target.value;
      }
      document.getElementById("user-input").focus();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

table {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../normalize.css">

  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <main>
    <input id="user-input">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" value="1" id="button-one" class="calc">1</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" value="2" class="calc">2</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" value="3" class="calc">3</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" value="4" class="calc">4</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" value="5" class="calc">5</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" value="6" class="calc">6</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" value="7" class="calc">7</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" value="8" class="calc">8</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" value="9" class="calc">9</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" value="0" class="calc">0</button></td>
        <td colspan="2"><button type="button" value="CLEAR" id="clear" class="calc">CLEAR</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works well too.  This one is closest to how I originally wrote it. I didn't know how to properly utilize "e" and "target". I was going to exclude "clear" and have a separate code for it but this is cleaner. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's totally valid to loop through a collection of buttons & attach an event listener to every one of those

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const userInput = document.getElementById("user-input")

  // get the collection of buttons -> OK
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("td > button");

  // in this for loop button is not a button object - it's just a NUMBER
  for (var button = 0; button < buttons.length; button++) {
    // you have to get access to the "button"th element in the buttons array
    // now THAT'S a button object -> you can attach an event listener to that
    buttons[button].addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (this.value === "CLEAR") {
        userInput.value = 0
      } else {
        // you have to cast the userInput's value to a number -> by default
        // that's not a number but a String!
        userInput.value = Number(userInput.value) + Number(this.value);
      }

      document.getElementById("user-input").focus();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

table {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <input id="user-input" type="text" value="0">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" value="1" class="calc">1</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" value="2" class="calc">2</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" value="3" class="calc">3</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" value="4" class="calc">4</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" value="5" class="calc">5</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" value="6" class="calc">6</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" value="7" class="calc">7</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" value="8" class="calc">8</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" value="9" class="calc">9</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" value="0" class="calc">0</button></td>
      <td colspan="2"><button type="button" value="CLEAR" id="clear" class="calc">CLEAR</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</main>
```